Usage of つもりだ with the past verb
適当にしたくない。　これでもずっと大事にしてきたつもりだ
"つもりだ" means "Intend to" but how is it used with a past verb? It's not I assume "I did plan to treasure them" because of the past? Is he talking about what he did until now?

これでも...つもりだ is a common phrase used to express that, (despite the challenge being made) someone had a certain intention or a certain standard that they have upheld.
これでも literally means "despite this" - probably best translated to "despite how it looks like", or "despite how it might look to you". "つもりだ" means what you describe is how you feel or what your subjective opinion was.
E.g. これでも魚なんだって(despite how it looks like (it doesn't look like a fish), apparently it's a type of fish).
E.g. 鍵をかけたつもりだった(I thought I locked it (but apparently it wasn't locked)).
And こいつこれでも魚のつもりらしいぜ (despite not looking like a fish, apparently this fish thinks it's a fish).

The solution is to interpret つもり differently. If you check jisho.org, "intend to" isn't the only definition. It can also mean "belief; assumption; thought; conviction".
So, 大事にしてきたつもりだ means something like "I believe / I think / I have conviction that I've treasured them up until now."

The connecting idea seems to be that the speaker has calculated or predicted something, but could be wrong. For future events, because the future is inherently uncertain; for past events, simply admitting doubt.
